# How to launch application after server startup using batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, launch, launching-application

```
@echo off
set START_SERVER="C:\Program Files\Apache\Tomcat_6\bin\startup.bat"
call %START_SERVER%
start http://localhost:8080/MyProject/
```

- How to launch app in browser after server start using batch?
- My above script is starting server and launching app.. but both working simultaneously.
- I want to launch app after server startup is done

Answer (score 1):

your code is right. The `start`will run, when `startup.bat` is finished.
The problem propably is in `startup.bat` Propably it starts an exe-file, and then exits, before that exefile is fully started.
You can edit `startup.bat` or set an `timeout`between the `call`line and the `start`line.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help any one but one can use timeout something like below:

@echo off
set START_SERVER="C:\Program Files\Apache\Tomcat_6\bin\startup.bat"
call %START_SERVER%
echo "Waiting 1 minutes for the application to start"
timeout /T 60
start http://localhost:8080/MyProject/